# Every Graph has one the following properties

Tags: graph-theory

> Let r be a positive integer. Then every G has one of the following properties:
>
> 1. G is $r$ colorable.
> 2. G contains an induced copy of some cycle on at most $2r+1$ vertices.
> 3. G contains an induced copy of every tree on $r$ vertices.

I tried the following thing but it seems I have got a  mistake:

Assuming that G isn't $r$ colorable means that [G is not $r-1$ degenerate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(graph_theory)#Relation_to_other_graph_parameters)
, so there is an induced subgraph $G_0$ of minimum degree at least $r$ , I wanted to use a theorem that says that if G has minimum degree $r$ it means that G contains any tree on $r+1$ vertices, so it contains an tree in $r$ vertices in particular.

Now assuming our graph doesn't have property (3) , it means that there is a subgraph of $G_0$ that is a tree on $r$ vertices , if it is not induced subgraph it means it contains a cycle , and that cycle can't be longer than $r$ edges...

Am I missing something?

Comment: This question was asked yesterday and had responses, but appears to have been deleted by the author.

Comment: @TravisJ actually I asked a little different thing a while ago , but it had no real responses (It was just some mistake in copyng the question) , I had an advance on the question , so this question is a little different , and since I felt that question became a little messy , I deleted , if I have done something wrong then I am sorry I didn't mean it , and it won't happen next time

Comment: People just get frustrated when they answer questions and then the question is deleted (the work they provided is lost, and they lose any rep they may have gained).  It is better, to just edit the existing question (clarifying your new understanding and removing typos, etc).

Comment: I think I get the idea behind your proof now and it is more elegant than the proof I gave, so I removed my answer. The only "mistake" I see in your proof is, that the writeup, especially of the second part is not very clear, but that is, at least partly, subjective.

Comment: But instead of getting cycle on $2r+1$ vertices I get a cycle on $r$ vetices , it soun fishy...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your graph doesn't have property 3, there is *some* tree $T$ on $r$ vertices that is not contained in $G$ as an induced subgraph.  To finish the proof you only need to reach a contradiction by constructing $T$.

So construct it.  Let $t_1$ be a vertex of $T$ and let $v_1$ be a vertex of $G_0$.  Assume $T$ is *rooted* at $t_1$.  Now $t_1$ has say $x<r$ children, and we will map these children arbitrarily to distinct neighbours of $v_1$.  We know these distinct neighbours exist because of the minimum degree of $G_0$, and we know that as we proceed through the tree $T$, mapping vertices further and further from $t_1$ to $G_0$, we will never reuse a vertex $v_k$ to which we have already mapped a vertex of $T$, because it would imply two distinct paths of length $<r$ from $v_1$ to $v_k$, which would imply the existence of a cycle of length $<2r$.

Comment: I still don't understand what I did wrong. I wasn't asked to construct one just show one exists.

If we have a connected graph that is not a tree , then it contains a cycle, so if T isn't induced , then we have two option.

1) $G_0$ doesn't contain T as subgraph. But I showed  that if $G$ is $r$ colorable then it is not possible

2)$G_0$ contains T but T isn't induced. So the subgraph on T's vertices contains a cycle (but why this is $\leq 2r+1$ and not $r$ since t is on $r$ vertices)